# Suggestions for bedroom exercises

Tags: exercise

At night I do sit-ups and push-ups. It started as something to knock me out, if I needed to sleep but wasn't tired, a few of each would tire me out.

As time passes I am able to do more before I get tired, and I don't find them a chore so much. Now I'm wandering what other exercises I can do at night just in my bedroom that don't require any equipment like sit-ups and push-ups?

These two are obvious ones that we all know, but what other exercises can I do? I don't have any specific goal like weight loss, or body building, just something that's good for me I can do at night.

Comment: You want exercises to help you sleep? or just general bedroom exercises?

Comment: You can try [the plank](http://www.todaysgolfer.co.uk/upload/35118/images/front-plank-exercise.jpg)? It's more challenging than it looks.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't more specific; Yes I would like exercise that will make me feel tired afterwards, so I can use them to tire my self out before bed if I'm too awake, but hopefully with the added bonus of doing a bit of exercise also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Diamond press ups
- Lunges
- Squats and Squat thrusts
- Pull ups (If you have something to pull up on)
- Stretches to improve flexibility

Look up plyometric or bodyweight exercises.

I will say however it will interrupt your sleep pattern training just before bed. Sometimes I feel I can tire myself out and it will help me sleep better but it never seems to work like that.

Comment: Some good points here. Thanks for the exercise ideas, also though, I am going to research further about exercise before sleep. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try squats, very good for balance and a good all-over leg exercise.  Look at the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squat_%28exercise%29) and go to the plyometric/bodyweight section for some variations

Comment: I will read up about squats, they look like the kind of thing I'm after, thanks!